# Python telebot script (take picture every minute and send to telegram)

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Hi I have been struggling with this script for a while and the last line is starting to drive me crazy. I want to take a picture every minute and send it to telegram.

```
import telebot
import picamera

# Set token
token = "PLACE TOKEN HERE"

# Connect to our bot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

# Sets the id for the active chat
chat_id=PLACE CHAT ID HERE

# Get the photo
camera=picamera.PiCamera()
camera.capture('./capture.jpg')
camera.close()

# Sends a message to the chat
bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=open('./capture.jpg', 'rb'))
```

ERROR: TypeError: send_photo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'photo'

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tested the code (without the picamera part) and it worked! I tried with and without `photo=` (just the `open()`) and still worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the script. If it helps anyone here is the code im currently using:

```
import time
import requests
import telebot
import picamera
from time import sleep

# Set token
token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Connect to our bot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

# Sets the id for the active chat
chat_id="xxxxxxxxx"

# Repeat function
def repeat():
    # Set camera
    camera=picamera.PiCamera()
    # Take picture
    camera.capture('./capture.jpg')
    # Camera close
    camera.close()
    # Send photo to telegram
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('capture.jpg', 'rb'))
    # Sleep 60 seconds
    time.sleep(60)
while True:
  repeat()
```

It works but sometimes the script will crash with one of these errors:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout())

Any idea how to solve those errors?